# How to install g++12 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, g++

I am working with some code that requires g++12 I was wondering how I could get this compiler on Ubuntu 20.4.4

If I need to install it from source how would I do that?

I have tried a few things with homebrew, and some other installers but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Although details are for version 11, it should still work for 12: https://iamsorush.com/posts/build-gcc11/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you were considering updating to a more recent long-term supported (LTS) version of Ubuntu, it might be a good time to do it now: Ubuntu 22.04LTS allows you to just install GCC 12's g++ using `apt install g++-12`, done. I predict that unless you have a lot of software depending on obsolete dependency libraries, updating your Ubuntu might be the easiest way to get `g++12`! (You can easily try that out in a `podman` or `docker` container, which I'll not go into here.)

If you're stuck to Ubuntu 20.04, I guess the cleanest and most straightforward way of getting `g++12` will be to try and backport the 22.04 `g++12` package. In that case, you don't have to worry about learning how to build GCC, and how to install a competing g++ that doesn't break all your system by interfering with existing compilers and even worse ABIs. Debian (and Ubuntu as kind-of-downstream of that) have taken the workload of learning that, and you just need to use their tools. Awesome!

Roughly speaking, the procedure to do that is this:

1. Prepare to build a Debian/Ubuntu package:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install -y build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev devscripts cmake debhelper-compat dh-python equivs
   ```
2. Get the package sources. You will need to find the link to the `.dsc` file on the [package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/g++-12):

   ```
   mkdir gcc-12
   cd gcc-12
   dget -u https://URL/OF/DSC/FILE.dsc
   ```
3. Install the build dependencies from the `.dsc`:

   ```
   mk-build-deps -i gcc-12*.dsc
   ```
4. Build the packages:

   ```
   cd gcc-12-somethingsomething
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -d
   ```

So far for theory. In practice, step 3 will fail – GCC12 depends on tools whose version shipped by Ubuntu 20.04 is simply too old. Especially, the Debian package says you'd need at least `g++11`, `binutils` >= 2.37.

This is really the point where *I* personally say *"If some software that I build needs a bleeding edge C++ compiler, it won't be happy with my Ubuntu 20.04 environment, anyway, and I need to update to a more modern Ubuntu"*. So, again **that's my recommendation; update to Ubuntu 22.04**, and then `apt install g++-12`.

If you want to live with the hassle, you will start to modify the `gcc-12-12.*/debian/control` and `rules.conf`, `rules2` files to depend on just *some* `g++` instead of `g++11`, disable ADA support, be less demanding of `binutils` etc.

However, you can be darn sure that the Debian folks thought about which versions of dependencies to use, and what fixes and backports to include. This is a rocky road. Probably less rocky than a "bare" source build, but it's an easy way to learn way more about GCC than you ever intended, and spend a couple of hours just to start the build.

Honestly, I keep repeating myself, but: if you suddenly find yourself in need of a modern compiler, it's a good time to update to a modern environment. That's way less pain and has way more benefits.

Comment: (1) I clicked on “Reject” in the Suggested Edit queue because this edit seemed to ignore the fact that you were making a distinction between the “g++12” product (not code formatted) and the `g++-12` package. I guess if you’re happy with all that code formatting, it’s OK with me. (2) Are you sure about `gcc-12-12.*`? Because [the package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/g++-12) seems to show `gcc-12_12.*` (the second punctuation character is an underscore, not a hyphen).